# How handle token expiry in jwt laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, api, laravel, jwt, laravel-5.3

I am developing mobile application back-end service using **laravel 5.3**. I am following REST API. Application having payment gateway integration and it needs more security.

I followed jwt auth by using the `tymon/jwt-auth` library for **laravel**.

I have few concern, my **token getting expired after 1 hour**, after that server returning token expired error and how application developer can handle this situation? Asking user to log in, again and again, is not possible.

How can app developer handle it?

What is the best and more secure approach?

Comment: I think JWT is a very good solution.  Just make sure your routes are using the `RefreshToken` middleware included in the package.  Also the config allows you to modify how long the token is valid for, though I think 1 hour should be plenty assuming you are using the `RefreshToken` middleware.

Comment: Thank you for reply,if I used this middle ware.how long my token get valid by default. or share good article describing this if any

Comment: That depends on what you have setup in the `config/jwt.php` file.  The default for token life is 1 hour.  If you have your routes using that RefreshToken middleware, you can keep refreshing it for up to two weeks (also modifiable in the config) before they need to login again.  Most if this is in the docs https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication

Answer (score 2):

in `config/jwt.php` change `'ttl' => 60` to whatever number you need, the numbers represent the minutes a token can live, but the best approach is to use the `RefreshToken`, since your app will be more secure from unwanted users.

Comment: Is is possible to provide the examples for using the RefreshToken always with app.